# Trouble uploading an image and save it on the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Below is my code for upload image.
Image is uploaded but the size of the uploaded image on server is **0 KB**.

```
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];   

    NSString *str_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someUrl.aspx?TaskId=%@",ID];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str_url];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@,",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UploadedFilePhysical\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",Phusicalstr1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Any idea what happened in the upload?

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
```

What is this line does?

How are you initializing this?

Replace it with something like this.

```
NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```